# Can't understand merge sort with python

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, mergesort

I'm studying algorithms, right now I'm stuck on merge sort code. As I understand, mergeSort() function takes a list and divides it into a sub list until it's length is less than two which is only one element and are assigned to left and right variables. After that it will pass these variables into merge() function which will sort left and right and place it into a new list and return this list. For example if the input is [4,3,2,1] then left=4 right=3, merge(left, right, compare) will return [3,4] and I'm stuck after that. Please help me to understand this example. Thanks.

```
import operator

def merge(left, right, compare):
    result = []
    i,j = 0, 0
    while i < len(left) and j < len(right):
        if compare(left[i], right[j]):
            result.append(left[i])
            i += 1
        else:
            result.append(right[j])
            j += 1
    while (i < len(left)):
        result.append(left[i])
        i += 1
    while (j < len(right)):
        result.append(right[j])
        j += 1
    return result

def mergeSort(L, compare = operator.lt):
    if len(L) < 2:
        return L[:]
    else:
        middle = len(L)//2
        left = mergeSort(L[:middle], compare)
        right = mergeSort(L[middle:], compare)
        return merge(left, right, compare)
```

Comment: `left=4 right=3` cannot be correct, because `left` and `right` are lists. You can see this because `left = mergeSort(...)` and `right = mergeSort(...)` are defined by what the `mergeSort` function returns, which is a list - and the use of `len(left)` and `len(right)` to get the list lengths in the `merge` function.

Comment: By the way, I have created an interactive demonstration of how the recursive merge sort algorithm is executed, which you might find helpful - select "merge_sort(4)" at the following link for a similar example to yours: https://werp.site/cs-toys/recursion.html

Comment: Yeah, I mean left = [4] right = [3], sorry

Comment: @kaya3 thank you so much, your demonstration is so helpful! Now I understand how it works. Thanks!

Comment: It should be noted that efficient merge sort functions involve a one time allocation of a temporary (working) array, and use indexes (or iterators or pointers) to indicate the boundaries of runs (for both top down and bottom up merge sort), and change the direction of merge based on level of recursion for top down, or base on iteration for bottom up, to avoid needless copying of data.